# DB2 Merge using multiple columns in ON statement

Tags: merge, db2

I have a megre statement that does something like the following:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_NAME1 tgt 
    USING (SELECT  CONTRACTOR, TRACTOR, COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_NAME2) src
    ON src.CONTRACTOR = tgt.CONTRACTOR AND src.TRACTOR = tgt.TRACTOR
```

This is because a contractor can have multiple tractors.  The table key is not used because it is an identity key only - auto number on insert.

The Merge runs OK when the table is empty, but when running it again it duplicates the rows where the tractor is null.  So I tried:

```
ON ((src.CONTRACTOR = tgt.CONTRACTOR AND src.TRACTOR = tgt.TRACTOR)
 OR (src.CONTRACTOR = tgt.CONTRACTOR AND tgt.TRACTOR IS NULL))
```

But this causes it to hang.  Does DB2 have an issue comparing NULL to NULL?

Answer (score 1):

*"Does DB2 have an issue comparing NULL to NULL?"* No, it does not. However, the result of such a comparison is *unknown*, in other words, it is neither `true` nor `false`:

```
$ db2 "select * from sysibm.sysdummy1"

IBMREQD
-------
Y      

  1 record(s) selected.

$ db2 "select * from sysibm.sysdummy1 where null = null"

IBMREQD
-------

  0 record(s) selected.

$ db2 "select * from sysibm.sysdummy1 where null != null"

IBMREQD
-------

  0 record(s) selected.
```

Without seeing your complete statement and sample data it's hard to provide a definite answer, but you may want to try instead:

```
...ON ((src.CONTRACTOR = tgt.CONTRACTOR AND src.TRACTOR = tgt.TRACTOR
        AND tgt.TRACTOR IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: You've said that "null tractors" create duplicate rows, which you don't want. If that's not the case, you may want to rephrase your question, adding some sample data, the current result, and the desired result.